# Find Duplicates By Created Date TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to find duplicates in a single table, where at least one of those duplicates was created in the last day.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DateOfBirth DOB, 
    FirstName FirstName, 
    LastName LastName, 
    COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM TABLE
WHERE DateOfBirth IS NOT NULL
    AND DATEDIFF(d,dateCreated,getDate()) <= 1
GROUP BY DateofBirth, FirstName, LastName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

The problem is that this query returns nothing, because both duplicates would need to be created within the last day (the way this reads).

I did some testing and found that this datediff requires that the `dateCreated` column both be within the datediff.

Any way to bring back these duplicates where the *most recent duplicate* was created within the last day? Even if the *oldest duplicate* was created a year ago?

Comment: and datecreated >= dateadd(d,-1,getdate())

Comment: Unfortunately, @drewlander, this does the same thing. It requires that both records be created within the last day.

Comment: maybe rownumber over partition would work then. Ill whip something together to check if the row_number is <> 1 and then include the same logic in that derived table.

Comment: Do you need to see both of them, or is just seeing the new duplicate good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, DateCreated, 
    TotalCount = COUNT(*) OVER
    (
      PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth
    )
  FROM dbo.[TABLE]
)
SELECT FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, DateCreated, TotalCount
  FROM x 
  WHERE TotalCount > 1 
  AND DateCreated >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

If you then want to eliminate those duplicates that were erroneously created in the last day, just change the outer query to:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  ...
)
DELETE x WHERE TotalCount > 1 
  AND DateCreated >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: I think you want to add an ORDER BY in your partition for dateCreated to ensure your lowest row is the oldest record.

Comment: @drewlander it's not a row_number(), order by is irrelevant. ALL rows (not just the last one) that have a dupe and that were created in the last 24 hours will be returned.

Comment: right.  if he only wants the duplicate then count shouldnt be used.  If he wants both records then it should.

Comment: @drewlander I'm not sure I understand your argument about why count shouldn't be used in either case. If he wants multiple rows (both the recent duplicate(s) and the older version(s)), he can just leave out the where clause having to do with DateCreated.

Comment: My understanding is if he has 3 records and no duplicate exists in the last 24 hours, then he doesnt want it.  If he has 3 records with a duplicate in the last 24 hours then he wants the two records created since the original row.  That is why row_number is important, if that is the case.

Comment: @drewlander you might be right, but that's not how I read it. Of course they could delete the duplicates that were created in the last day, then run the original query again without the WHERE clause relating to DateCreated, and find any remaining duplicates.

Comment: One of those two solutions will work.   Thanks for pointing out the count issue and correcting that.

Comment: I am not confident that running the query twice would be sufficent. Il be happy to explain why in chat so we dont carry on in this thread.

Comment: @drewlander I'd rather not go on and on about why you think my solution might not be meeting the OP's expectations. Unless you're the OP, let's let the OP comment on what works or doesn't, and why.

Comment: @drewlander, Aaron Bertrand, I appreciate so much the assistance, as well as the debate. I apologize I did not make my needs clearer. This will be an ongoing analysis tactic and as such will need to return a row for everything (original and duplicate). Aaron's answer will help best moving forward, but I have filed away both. I wish I could accept both, because I would!

Answer (score 1):

I have revised this as an alternative to Aarons answer, in case you wish to see only the duplicates which are not the original record.

```
   ;WITH x AS 
    (
      SELECT FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, DateCreated, 
         Row_number() OVER
        (
          PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth
        order by dateCreated) as rowNumber
      FROM dbo.[TABLE1]
    )
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, DateCreated, rowNumber
      FROM x 
      WHERE rowNumber > 1 
      AND DateCreated >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: I get a Msg 8120 error because of the COUNT(*) line. You can't include that in the inner query unless you also use GROUP BY.

Comment: @aaron-bertrand, I didnt test it, just wrote it on the fly.  You win this one ;-)

Comment: Not trying to win anything, just giving advice on improving your answer and making it correct.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron-bertrand.  I added this answer back as an alternative dependings on the OP's needs.

Comment: As stated, I upvoted this because it will also help. I wish I could accept both answers, I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, without using a CTE:

```
SELECT 
     DOB =          t.DateOfBirth
    ,FirstName =    t.FirstName
    ,LastName =     t.LastName
    ,TotalCount =   COUNT(*)

FROM 
    TABLE t
WHERE   
    (NOT t.DateOfBirth IS NULL)
    AND EXISTS
       (
        SELECT * 
        FROM 
            TABLE nt 
        WHERE 
            DATEDIFF(d,nt.dateCreated,getDate()) <= 1 
            AND nt.FirstName = t.FirstName 
            AND nt.LastName = t.LastName
            AND nt.DateOfBirth = t.DateOfBirth
        )
GROUP BY 
    t.DateofBirth
    ,t.FirstName
    ,t.LastName
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
 ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: What is wrong with a CTE? Do you have an aversion to them? Maybe you mean to have one against *recursive* CTEs?

Comment: Honestly I cant even get this code to execute. I Created a mock table, and first noticed the extra comma after dateofbirth, then there are other issues.

Comment: Also, there are syntax errors here (extra comma on line 2, all of the `t.*` instances don't parse because that is invalid). Also note that two full scans have to be performed (or whatever operation is supported by any indexes that we don't know about), and it isn't easy to change this query to one which can issue a delete of the dupes.

Comment: That was my other concern.  Its not easy to convert to delete.

Comment: CTEs are not supported in older versions of T-SQL. The question did not indicate which version of T-SQL he was using.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to see the most recent, you can get away with a simple self-join:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 on t1.DateofBirth = t2.DateofBirth and t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName and t1.Lastname = t2.LastName
WHERE t2.DateCreated <> t1.DateCreated 
   AND t2.DateCreated > DATEADD(d, -1, current_timestamp)
```

If you need to see *every* instance of the record, you could try putting both the `t1` and `t2` values in the select list in the query above. If you want them as separate records, you can join to the above query as *derived table*:

```
SELECT t3.* 
FROM Table t3
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t2.DateofBirth, t2.FirstName, t2.LastName
    FROM table t1
    INNER JOIN table t2 on t1.DateofBirth = t2.DateofBirth and t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName and t1.Lastname = t2.LastName
    WHERE t2.DateCreated <> t1.DateCreated 
       AND t2.DateCreated > DATEADD(d, -1, current_timestamp)
) sub on t3.DateofBirth = sub.DateofBirth and t3.FirstName = sub.FirstName and t3.Lastname = sub.LastName
```

Comment: Note that this pattern requires two scans rather than one, and in general doesn't scale linearly but rather exponentially (as the table gets larger, it takes longer and longer to process a self-join).